# Monogame Windows 8 error - Deployment failed because an app with target platform ARM cannot be deployed to Emulator

Tags: monogame

When i try and run the emulator I'm getting the following....

Deployment failed because an app with target platform ARM cannot be deployed to Emulator 720P. If the target platform is win32/ x86, select an emulator. If the target platform is ARM, select Device

Any ideas? I've tried to adjust the configuration to X86 to no avail?

Comment: Do you have a real device to test on? The emulator is not particularly good at the best of times and may not work with MonoGame at all.

Comment: I do, I've literally just got it unlocked.... I'd rather have the emulator though whilst debugging for speed of development.

Comment: Unfortunately the emulator will actually make development slower. What I do is make the game on windows first and port it to Android later testing on the real device.

Comment: I'm glad you said that. I've just watched an XNA tutorial on pluralsight. The demo was in windows so I considered the same thing and port across as you say.

Answer (score 6):

let try to change the value "ARM" to "x86" by **BUILD -> CONFIGURATION MANAGER**

Answer (score 0):

Batero is correct. But also, note that you Configuration Manager allows you to have separate build targets depending on the profile you are building with.

So you could configure it to build x86 when you are in Debug mode and ARM when you are in the Release mode.